# Javadoc displaying value on an inner class constant using @value

Tags: java, annotations, constants, javadoc

I have an inner class which declares a constant and want to display its value in Javadoc of the enclosing top-level class using the @value annotation. For example:

```
/**
 * {@value #FOO_CONS} // this displays well
 * {@value #BAR_CONS} // this does not work (checked in the latest Eclipse)
 * {@value Bar#BAR_CONS} // this does not work, either
 */
public Foo {
  public static final int FOO_CONS = 1;
  static class Bar {
    public static final int BAR_CONS = 42;
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to display the value of BAR_CONS in Javadoc of the `Foo` class (or any other class, in general)?

Comment: Did you try using `@value Foo.Bar#BAR_CONS` as stated [here][1], it takes the same form as the @see argument, and as stated [here][2] `Nested classes must be specified as outer.inner, not simply inner, for all forms.`
I don't have eclipse here so I'm not able to test further. Otherwise the fully qualified path should work `com.pkg.Foo.Bar#BAR_CONS`


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@value%7D
  [2]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#package.class

Comment: Yes, that does not work, at least it is not displayed correctly in Eclipse. What's more I cannot even get FOO_CONS displayed correctly with {@value Foo#FOO_CONS}.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using ? I can remember the `@value` annotation not showing correctly prior to Helios.

Comment: Indigo (3.7.2). Does the above example work fine in your Eclipse (if you use @value as you described)?

Comment: My Indigo gives the same results as OP stated in his comments.

Comment: After further tests it does not work in Juno either. If using `Bar#BAR_CONS` when moving the cursor on it in the javadoc, eclipse correctly highlight the instance in the inner class, the java doc eclipse view does not correctly show it. I don't know why.

Comment: @Alex has hit on something useful. I tested the fully qualified path and had success. 

Foo was in package "org.oyrm.javadoc" and the annotation reads `{@value org.oyrm.javadoc.Foo.Bar#BAR_CONS}`

Answer (score 15):

Javadoc format for constant defined in another package should be:
{@value package.class#field}

However, it potentially not rendering is a known issue:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342194

Answer (score 2):

if create javadoc for members with visibility "package" (which is the visibility for your Bar class) i get the constant in the javadoc under Foo.Bar